# How to divide a HTML table using percentages

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am using a HTML template in my website that send emails and one of the sections in the email uses HTML tables.

How can i use HTML to get the following output
[image]

Here is a fiddle to [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/duJLR/) what i have tried

Here is my HTML code

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="background-color:#d9eeff;"><strong>Order Details</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <strong>Order ID:</strong>

            </td>
            <td>XSL VALUE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <strong>Date:</strong>

                <br />
                <br />
            </td>
            <td>XSL VALUE
                <br />
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <strong>Payment Method:</strong>

                <br />
                <br />
            </td>
            <td>XSL VALUE
                <br />
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <strong>Shipping Method:</strong>

                <br />
                <br />
            </td>
            <td>XSL VALUE
                <br />
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your colspan is wrong - you only have 2 columns so try colspan="2"

Comment: Could you explain the difference between the expected the output and the jsfiddle?

Comment: Well. Basically i  dont know how to get that dividing line. I want the first column to have width 60% and second to have width 40%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your HTML to set `colspan` to `2` and also add a `thead` in order to maintain correct semantics. Other than that, as is the joy of HTML email, you're likely best applying your CS inline...*shudder*.

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/LxD9N/3/)

HTML

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;">
    <thead>
        <tr style='background:lightgray;'>
            <td colspan="2" style="padding:5px;font-weight:bold;">Order Details</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:5px 0 0 5px;font-weight:bold;border-right:1px solid lightgray;width:50%;">Order ID: <span style='font-weight:normal;'>(value)</span>
            </td>
            <td style='padding-left:20px;'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:5px;font-weight:bold;border-right:1px solid lightgray;width:50%;">Date: <span style='font-weight:normal;'>(value)</span>
            </td>
            <td style='padding-left:20px;font-weight:bold;'>Email: <span style='font-weight:normal;'>(value)</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:5px;font-weight:bold;border-right:1px solid lightgray;width:50%;">Payment Method: <span style='font-weight:normal;'>(value)</span>
            </td>
            <td style='padding-left:20px;font-weight:bold;'>Telephone: <span style='font-weight:normal;'>(value)</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:0 0 5px 5px;font-weight:bold;border-right:1px solid lightgray;width:50%;">Shipping Method: <span style='font-weight:normal;'>(value)</span>
            </td>
            <td style='padding-left:20px;'></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This looks much neater than my approach. But can you suggest how to get the diving line so i can add the other 2 rows(email and telephone). Should i nest another table within table?

Comment: I've updated the link with styling, not sure what exactly you mean though?

Comment: I mean how do i get it to look like the pic i posted in the question

Answer (score 1):

```
<HTML>

<BODY>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse">
    <thead>
            <td colspan="3" style="background-color:#d9eeff;"><strong>Order Details</strong>
            </td>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Order Id:<td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date:<td>
            <td>Email:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Payment Method:<td>
            <td>Telephone:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipping Method:<td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

**USE THIS HTML CODE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/mkginfo/vWy6R/

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="background-color:#d9eeff;"><strong>Order Details</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" width="50%">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> <strong>Order ID:</strong>

                    </td>
                    <td>XSL VALUE</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <strong>Date:</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>XSL VALUE
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <strong>Payment Method:</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>XSL VALUE
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <strong>Shipping Method:</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>XSL VALUE
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" width="50%">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> <strong></strong></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <strong>Email:</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>XSL VALUE

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <strong>Telephone:</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>XSL VALUE

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <strong></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to count your TD Tags

as you specified td colspan="3"  in the first row

all other rows should at least have 3 td tags or td tags specifiying a colspan value.

and my advice use CSS instead. If not possible count how much columns you need and respect the previous rules

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;">
    <thead>
        <tr style='background:#c0c0c0;'>
            <td colspan="2" style="padding:5px;"><strong>Order Details</strong>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:5px 0 0 5px;font-weight:bold;border-right:1px solid black;">Order ID:</td>
            <td style="padding:0 0 0 5px;">XSL VALUE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:5px;font-weight:bold;border-right:1px solid black;">Date:</td>
            <td style="padding:0 0 0 5px;">XSL VALUE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:5px;font-weight:bold;border-right:1px solid black;">Payment Method:</td>
            <td style="padding:0 0 0 5px;">XSL VALUE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:0 0 5px 5px;font-weight:bold;border-right:1px solid black;">Shipping Method:</td>
            <td style="padding:0 0 0 5px;">XSL VALUE</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/UwRJ9/)

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duJLR/1/)
**HTML Code**

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#d9eeff;"><strong>Order Details</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <strong>Order ID:</strong>

                        </td>
                        <td>XSL VALUE</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <strong>Date:</strong>

                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                        <td>XSL VALUE
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <strong>Payment Method:</strong>

                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                        <td>XSL VALUE
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <strong>Shipping Method:</strong>

                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                        <td>XSL VALUE
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <strong>Email:</strong>

                        </td>
                        <td>XSL VALUE</td>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <strong>Telephone:</strong>

                            </td>
                            <td>XSL VALUE</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*Hope this might help..!!*